# Does open stairs between basement and main living cost extra electricity bill?

Tags: electrical, hvac, heating, stairs

Does with No door or open stairs between basement and main living lead extra electricity bill, specially in winter, even though entire basement is finished and well insulated ?

We want to have open stairs for basement and no door.

Thanks

Comment: Is basement heated?  A heated basement should not make much difference if door open or close.  An unheated basement could make a bigger difference in bill, since it acts as a cold sink.

Comment: Leave the door open for a month and see if your bill jumps. It would depend on how your hvac system is set up.

Comment: Yes. basement is heated. actually I am finishing my basement currently. the stairs has wall on both sides and right now there is a door on one side. I have to remove wall of once side before contractor hang drywall in basement.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if your "heating bill" already includes heating the basement.  If you have forced air heating or cooling with the basement on the same zone as the living area, it should make no difference because the air is already circulating and mixing.

If you heat your basement and it's on a separate zone, your bill might go up as the zones will not work as efficiently.  If you do not currently heat your basement, your bill for the upstairs might go up. Or, it might go down if your basement is naturally warm (say, that's where the furnace is) and the new arrangement allows warm air to rise upstairs more efficiently.

You didn't ask about cooling but if you have cooling upstairs but not downstairs and your basement is not naturally cool in summer, your cooling bill will go up, possibly a lot as the cool air generated for upstairs will have to fill the basement before it can begin cooling the living area.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, door open/closed of a well insulated basement does not really affect the heating energy consumption of the house.

However, there is a subjective element that could cause you to heat more.

Even if the heat bill stays the same, you might find it colder in the basement, with the door open/absent: with an open/absent door, cold air from the main level will drop into the basement, despite cold air intake on the main level.

If you then turn up the thermostat to get a warmer basement, or if you throttle (partially close) the vents on the main level to force more hot air into the basement for a higher temperature there, you will be heating more in total.

This means you will have a higher heating bill with the door open/absent.

But, much depends on the location of your thermostat, the location of your return air intakes (is there an intake on the main and the basement level?), and the insulation of your basement considering the number of doors, sizes of windows etc..

Compare this to the situation where you sit near a hot air vent or sit near a cold window on a cold day; and you set the thermostat accordingly to feel comfortable in that spot. Where you sit does not affect the efficiency of the house, but it does affect the heat bill.